# Does Set-PnPFileCheckedIn.cs support folders?

Tags: powershell, pnp

I have a document which is two folders deep in a document library. When I try and use Set-PnPFileCheckedIn with a Url like "/Documents/Incorporation/Objections/incorporation objection.docx" I get an error :-

```
" Set-PnPFileCheckedIn : Server relative urls must start with SPWeb.ServerRelativeUrl"
```

if I add in -Web /sites/board/archives I get the same error.  If I change the -Web parameter to be sites/board/archives I get the error message

> "Set-PnPFileCheckedIn : File Not Found."

Anybody any ideas ?
 
Thanks
 
Nigel

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a problem with a space in the url between incorporation and objection